# Shopify transaction admin api giving 404

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to hit transaction api to get transactions against the checkout but somehow its giving me 404 although I am following all the right steps. Can someone help me figure out please ?

```
POST /admin/orders/#{order_id}/transactions.json
```

{
  "transaction": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "amount": "10.00",
    "kind": "capture",
    "parent_id": 389404469
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with parent_id you're passing and causes 404 as it was not found.

`parent_id`: The ID of an associated transaction.

- For capture transactions, the parent needs to be an authorization transaction.
- For void transactions, the parent needs to be an authorization transaction.
- For refund transactions, the parent needs to be a capture or sale transaction.

You can try other options if it is useful:

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "kind": "capture",
    "authorization": "authorization-key"
  }
}
```

Source: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/transaction

**Edit:**

### Getting `parent_id`

Use GET /admin/orders/#{order_id}/transactions.json API. You'll get a transactions

```
{
    transactions: [{
        id: 656371876577,
        order_id: 586887654355,
        kind: "sale",
        gateway: "Cash on Delivery (COD)",
        status: "pending",
        message: "Pending the Cash on Delivery (COD) payment from the buyer",
        created_at: "2018-07-18T10:27:39-04:00",
        test: false,
        authorization: null,
        location_id: null,
        user_id: null,
        parent_id: null,
        device_id: null,
        receipt: {},
        error_code: null,
        source_name: "web",
        amount: "20.06",
        currency: "USD"
    }]
}
```

Here 656371876577 is the `parent_id` of the transaction.
If there is no parent transaction, you can pass null as `parent_id`

Comment: aren't we passing order id as parent ? We are handling transactions outside stripe btw

Comment: sorry @raj. It is actually this api which is giving me 404 GET /admin/checkouts/#{token}/payments.json